# twitter like relational db?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, relational-database

I'm currently trying to make a small web service, just for fun and learning. (I recently started to learn programming practically.)
The service is like twitter. users follow their friends and get statuses of them.

I have a question about relational db.

There are 3 tables, which are 'user','friendship' and 'status'.
here are codes to describe what these tables look like.

```
    create table user (
    id int unsigned auto_increment primary key,
    username varchar(16) not null,
    password varchar(255) not null,
    created datetime default null
    );

    create table friendship (
    id int unsigned auto_increment primary key,
    userid int not null,
    friend int not null,
    created datetime default null
    );

    create table status (
    id int unsigned auto_increment primary key,
    userid int not null,
    current_status int not null,
    created datetime default null
    );
```

'user.id' is equal to 'friendship.userid' and 'status.userid'.

・The situation is;

1, a user logged in, and will get his friends' status numbers.

2, php got the user's id and find his friends's userid, username, status and created (of status).

I tried some sql sentences but not working.

Could any super sql writer show me correct sql ?

Cheers!

Edited 1;

I tried sql like this;

```
    select userid, username, current_status, created
    from status
    join users u1
    on u1.id = status.userid
    join friendship
    on friendship.friend = u1.id
    join user u2
    on u2.id =friendship.userid
    where u2.id = "the user's id from php";
```

and mysql throw this "#1146 - Table 'Application.user' doesn't exist."

Comment: You should show some of your attempted SQL.

Comment: also, what is status.current_status supposed to be? It seems like it should be a varchar (is that the tweet portion of db)

Comment: This question lacks research. Nothing more than creating tables is done. There a long way to go dude.

Comment: hi Nathan, status is logiced in php to translate to detail setence, and the status I want to get is current_status as you point!

Comment: and I edited to add some info, thx!

Comment: hi, katti. I spend this whole day...but Google and any book is helpful, so take this place. thx advising anyway.

Comment: There's a typo in line 7 of your query: `user` should be `users`. You'll also need to specify which of three columns called `created` MySQL should return, like this: `table.column`.

Comment: One more suggestion. In your table, you have the createdtime, but you default it to NULL.  You should default it to the current time.  In mysql, this would use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

Comment: The error message tells you the exact problem. Try reading it...

Comment: hi Gordon. oh thats why, I changed it as you told. glad you answer! thx.

Comment: hi usr, thanks. my tiny tiny mistake caused every error. thx !

Answer (score 1):

Your first join statement has "users" while your table name is "user." This is a common newbie error. You should pick  standard and follow it. Most DBs that I see use the singular form, so there is no confusion whether your tables names are "friends" or "friend."

Not to worry though, I think practically everyone makes this mistake when starting out. There might be other errors, but this one pops out immediately.

Try fixing that and letting us know how it goes.

Oh, and in table selects declare which table I am selecting from: i.e. SELECT from user.userid, …

Comment: I fixed it. I'm disappointed with myself.. but now its working exactly as I expected. thanks a lot!

Comment: Oh. This was a while ago (over 1year). If this fixed it, then please rate is as Answered. Thanks. I wouldn’t be too disappointed though. I have kicked myself for making minor errors that resulted in fatal errors and looked for days trying to find the culprit. In those cases, I take a braek then come back with fresh eyes, checking that each variable declaration and use matches others. Decent code editors and IDEs help immensely with syntax checks and code reflection to prevent those boggling bugs, though.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
select u1.userid, username, current_status, created
from status
    inner join [user] u1 on u1.id = status.userid
    inner join friendship on friendship.friend = u1.id
    inner join [user] u2 on u2.id = friendship.userid
    where u2.id = @User2Id
```

Like was mentioned in the comments: Table 'Application.user' doesn't exist

In SQL Server user is a reserved word so we add the square braces around it. (see code). Or you change the table name to be something else (IE Client, TwitterUser, etc...)

Comment: Thank you so much. changed my sql like yours. actually I think I need to learn sql and spend certain time :( thx anyway!

Comment: oh, and I added "status." to "creaeted" in the select statement cuz sql says its ambiguous.